# User-Item based Recommendation system with data containing binary data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data, recommender-system

I have a data set which contains about 400,000 unique items present on a platform. The users on this platform can like and save this in their own list. Now, I have about 4000 users with their like data which looks like this

```
| UserID | ItemID | 
|  1     |   3    |
|  1     |   4    |
|  1     |   10   |
|  1     |   13   |
|  2     |   3    |
|  2     |   40   |
|  3     |   1    |
|  3     |   23   |
```

An item will only be present against the user-item pair only when the user likes an item. I am trying to recommend items to other users/users to other users using User-User/User-Item Collaborative filtering but I couldn't find any leads on how to achieve that using python. Any help on this would really be appreciated!

Comment: You can checkout library like Lightfm with BPR (bayesian personalized rating) criteria https://making.lyst.com/lightfm/docs/lightfm.html

Comment: @hssay Correct me if I'm wrong but LightFM library uses ratings to compute recommendations, right?

Comment: Afaik, LightFM supports implicit feedback models (where no explicit ratings available) based on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.2618.pdf this paper. So it will be worth trying by using 1/0 weights and BPR as a criteria. The example is covered in https://making.lyst.com/lightfm/docs/examples/movielens_implicit.html where they treat rating as implicit

Comment: In the example that you shared above, I'm unable to see how they made the CSR matrix. So for a dataset that I showed in the question above, how do I go about creating the train and test datasets?